# Why isn't the first digit being included in the slice [:3]?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a short script that tells whether or not a [ticket is lucky](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/168923/count-the-lucky-tickets-within-the-given-range), without the use of functions, math etc. I'm printing half1 and half2 for now just so I can see the output.

```py
# Save the input in this variable
ticket = input()

# Add up the digits for each half
half1 = int(str(ticket)[:3])
half2 = int(str(ticket)[3:6])

print(half1)
print(half2)

# Thanks to you, this code will work
if half1 == half2:
    print("Lucky")
else:
    print("Ordinary")
```

The problem is, Python is always slicing off the first digit for half1, but slicing the last 3 digits for half2 like it should.

For example if I enter: 090234

The first 3 digits add up to 9 and the last 3 also add up to 9.

So print result should be "Lucky". However, Python isn't including the initial 0, despite me telling it to with the [:3] slice.

If I remove int( from both half1 and half2. It will include the first digit, but then it prints ordinary. I understand why because the numbers are different, but I don't understand why the slice isn't correctly taking the first 3 digits of the 6 digits the user enters, and instead is omitting the first digit always.

Comment: are you using Python 2.x or 3.x? The behaviour of `input()` differs between those - in 2.x `input` converts entered numbers to apriopriate numeric types, so `090234` becomes just `90234`. Basically, you should use `raw_input` instead of `input` if it is Python 2.x.

Comment: Without a `+` operator, there will not be a sum. `int()` does not calculate a sum

Comment: @Błotosmętek I'm using Python3. & Thomas I knew I forgot a step too... Thank you!

Comment: `input` function returns `str` object and no need write `str` function as parameter of `int` function

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan if I didn't include str, I got 'object not iterable'.

Comment: @pythonInRelay Nope. 'object not iterable` in this context  means that `input()` returned an int instead of a string. This means Python 2.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of your cast to int, python is not keeping the leading 0s on int objects:

```
>>> number = int("000012")
>>> number
12
```

What you want is to keep that string and add its digits:

```
>>> entry = "090234"
>>> print(sum(map(int, entry[:3]))) # leading 3 digits
9
>>> print(sum(map(int, entry[-3:]))) # last 3 digits
9
```

Comment: Slightly shorter: `sum(map(int, entry[:3]))` (but your version is certainly clearer)